# RSS feed reader that allows for commenting directly from the app

Tags: android, rss, feed-reader

I read a lot of blogs on my Android device using an RSS feed reader (Feedly). If I want to comment on a blog, I need to leave the app and go to the corresponding website, which is quite slow.

Are there any Android apps that would allow me to both read an RSS feed from a blog and comment to that blog from the app directly?

Comment: Where do you want these comments to appear?

Comment: This first would require the corresponding blog/site to support this (not all blogs allow for comments – and most of those that do require the user to be logged in at least). // As your question was already flagged for being unclear, may I suggest you taking a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) – and then see that you can [edit] and implement some improvements? Also be welcome to check my list of [RSS Readers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/reading_rss) for Android.